# Рандомизация чисел

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, я занимаюсь программированием на С++ и пытаюсь написать консольную программу, чтобы она выдавала числа наугад от 0 до 9, при этом числа перемещались бы сверху вниз, как в старом добром фильме "Матрица". Я столкнулся с проблемой. Когда программа выбирает число наугад, оно остается фиксированным. Вот код:

```
   #include <Windows.h>;
    #include <iostream>;
    using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute (hStdout, FOREGROUND_GREEN + 
                                    FOREGROUND_INTENSITY); // Цвет для текста

    char Matr = rand() % 9 + 48;  // Попытка сделать случайный выбор числа

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo (hStdout, &csbi);

    const int WindWidth = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;     //Константа, определяющая ширину окна
    const int WindHeight = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;    //Высота окна

    for(int i = 0; i < WindWidth * WindHeight; i++)
        cout << " ";                                    //изначальная заливка всей консоли пробелами

    COORD orig = {0, 0};                                //Координаты начала консоли

    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hStdout, orig);

    COORD num[250];                                     //Массив, явно превышающий размеры окна консоли. Чтобы цифры шли по всему экрану

    for(int i = 0; i<WindWidth; i++)
    {
        num[i].X = i;                                   // Х существует в каждой клетке
        num[i].Y = rand() % WindHeight;                 // Координаты по Y в разбросанном порядке

    }

    while (true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < WindWidth; i++)
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition (hStdout, num[i]);
            cout << ' ';

            num[i].Y++;

            if(num[i].Y == WindHeight)
                num[i].Y = 0;

            SetConsoleCursorPosition (hStdout, num[i]);
            cout << Matr;
            }
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hStdout, orig);       //Перемещение курсора на начало во избежании появления 26 строки
            Sleep(55);

    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Меня интересует, как можно сделать так, чтобы каждый раз выбиралось новое число. Мне нужно, чтоб число (к примеру 2), дойдя до нижнего края, появлялось наверху, при этом превращаясь в другое число. И при этом чтоб на каждой координате Х были разные числа, которые выбираются наугад заново каждый раз, коснувшись нижней границы. У меня есть предположение, что это нужно сделать с помощью массивов, но, честно говоря сейчас уже поздно соображаю, поэтому прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо :)

**UPD** Если это слишком сложно и потребует глобальной перестройки кода, можно не делать так, чтоб каждое число при проходе нижней границы менялось. Просто чтоб хотя бы на каждой иксовой координате было своё число.

Comment: Код `rand() % 9 + 48` даст символ от '0' до '8'. Надо делить на 10, а не на 9.

Comment: что-то сильно мудренно для вывода на экран рэндомных чисел на подобие матрицы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявите Matr как массив символов, забейте его случайными символами, а в цикле выводите i-й элемент этого массива.

```
char *Matr = new char[WindWidth];
for (int i = 0; i < WindWidth; i++)
    Matr[i] = rand() % 9 + 48;

....

while (true)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < WindWidth; i++)
        {
            ....
            SetConsoleCursorPosition (hStdout, num[i]);
            cout << Matr[i];
        }
        ....
}
```

При таком варианте число не будет меняться при проходе через границу. Если нужно, чтобы менялось, отслеживай этот момент и забивай в Matr[i] новый случайный символ.

Comment: надо также учитывать, что это псевдослучайные числа. и надо использовать какой-то все время изменяющийся ключ -- например функция time() из библиотеки ctime(или time.h)